# How do I clone a Firefox profile in windows?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, clone, firefox-profile

I've copied `%appdata%/mozilla/firefox/profiles/myprofile1` into `%appdata%/mozilla/firefox/profiles/myotherprofile2` but if I do a text search inside the files of either profile directory you can see that some files like `prefs.js`, `extensions.ini`, `extensions.sqlite`, `search.json`, `secmod.db`, `startupCache.4.little` or `TestPilotErrorLog.log` have the string at least `myprofile1` embedded and actually in some cases full paths.

Is it safe to leave these as it is?

What is a better way to clone a firefox profile?

---

Reason: I would like to clone my profile because I would like to measure differences between several Firefox binary versions "in practice", ie. the way I use them, and also the impact of installing specific extensions, although it could be done without the clone (still it would be handy to clone). In future maybe I want to use multiple different firefox versions at the same time due for addon compatibility reasons. I have >100 extensions, would like to avoid to do it manually|[febe](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/febe/)|[history export](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/history-export/) to *retain maximum match*.

**edit** since then I've edited `%appdata%/mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini` to include my copied profile, now it shows up in profile manager, but I'm concerned about the path values I found in the files, they seemed to be fixed to the original path.

Comment: Isn't the Profile Manager good enough? You can recover profiles there so you can you this function to essentially clone profiles.

Comment: @matan129 I'd love to! but I don't know how: I see `Create Profile`, `Rename Profile`, `Delete Profile`, `Work offline`, `Don't ask at startup`, `Start Firefox`, `Exit`, and dominantly a list of my profiles as 'display names'. When I copied my profile folder, the named profile in this list was not duplicated. So either there is a register or index to them, or because of the colliding names it wasn't displayed. I tried to right-click a profile name but nothing happened, while double-right click is the same as double-left click in effect. How to do the recover functionality you speak of?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new profile using the `Profile manager`, let's call it `test profile`. Then back-up the current profile using [MozBackup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mozbackup/), then restore that backup to the newly created `test profile`.

Comment: didn't know about [MozBackup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mozbackup/), thanks! I shall test this promising method...