# Firefox, multiple instances

Tags: firefox

firefox -p -no-remote allows a different profile to be used, with multiple instances of Firefox by the same user. I would like to have the profile cloned, so that the same profile is used in different instances. Does Firefox support this?

I realize I could likely write a script for this, but I sm looking for an application solution, if one exists.

The platform is Slackware 14.2 with KDE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clone a Firefox profile in windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/616536/how-do-i-clone-a-firefox-profile-in-windows)

Comment: Not a duplicate, as I am trying to have the instantiation perform the cloning.